# How can I satisfy promises aplus spec 2.2.4 in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am writing an HTTP Promises package for nodeJS. I need it to be promises aplus compliant. I am using promises-aplus-tests - https://www.npmjs.com/package/promises-aplus-tests

I have created an adapter as follows:

```
var adapter = {
        deferred: function() {
            var d = {}
            d.promise = new HTTPromise(new GETOptions('/path', DEFAULT_OPTIONS));
            d.resolve = executorResponseFunc;
            d.reject = executorRejectFunc;        
            return d;
        }
    }

promisesAplusTests(adapter, function (err) {
    done(err);
});
```

My tests are failing on https://promisesaplus.com/#point-34 ...
with further help on https://promisesaplus.com/#point-67

> 2.2.4 onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution
> context stack contains only platform code
>
> 3.1 Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise
> implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that
> onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event
> loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be
> implemented with either a “macro-task” mechanism such as setTimeout or
> setImmediate, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as
> MutationObserver or process.nextTick. Since the promise implementation
> is considered platform code, it may itself contain a task-scheduling
> queue or “trampoline” in which the handlers are called.

But I can't get it passing this promises aplus test. I am using the bog standard JavaScript Promises library (which on its own passes the tests) documented at ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

new Promise(executor);

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ... });

In the executor I have tried ...

```
if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    process.nextTick(() => {
        resolve(finalResponse);   
    });
} else {
    process.nextTick(() => {
        reject(finalResponse);
    });
}
```

and also ...

```
process.nextTick(() => {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        resolve(finalResponse);      
    } else {
         reject(finalResponse);
    }
});
```

There seems to be a lot of talk on the Internet but not many code examples of how to comply. Is there a code sample on how to satisfy this test and how you would use nextTick or another suitable solution?

It's worthing mentioning I have another call to reject within an HTTP error handler within the executor function.

Comment: Why are you writing your own promise library instead of simply using one the existing (and wrap the HTTP stuff in it)? Or if you already are using the builtin `Promise`, why do you run the aplus tests on it? There is no reason to use `nextTick` with a compliant `new Promise` constructor.

Comment: Where are `executorResponseFunc` and `executorRejectFunc` coming from?!

Comment: Can you show your complete code, please? I have no idea what you're trying to do, or what problem a `HTTPPromise` is supposed to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bergi they have helped my thinking - please could you look at my answer to myself and verify my thinking is OK now - many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to apologise to Bergi, I think I have the answer to my stupidity but I would appreciate confirmation that my thinking is now correct ...

My initial confusion came from ...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

I am writing a similar but more powerful npm tool.
They have the "then" badge, so obviously I wanted it!
I thought I needed to pass your tests (they have made some kind of attempt at it).
So I tried to pass your promises-aplus-tests
 with my library, which uses promises heavily but is NOT a promise implementation.

I see ...
https://www.npmjs.com/package/promises-aplus-tests

says

> This suite tests compliance of a promise implementation with the
>   Promises/A+ specification.

So I realise now that my package does NOT need to pass your tests and I am not as clever as I might have hoped :)

However, I am running a test to ensure that the Promise library we are using passes your tests during the build process. If it does not the build will fail.

My code is now ...

```
class HTTPromise {
    constructor(options) {
        ... blah blah blah
        let executor = THE_REAL_EXECUTOR;
        return AppPromise(executor);
    } 
}

class HTTPromiseCompliance {
    constructor(executor) {
        return AppPromise(executor);
    }
}
```

AppPromise looks like ...

```
module.exports = executor => {
    return new Promise(executor);
}
```

and finally the test suite ...

```
describe('HTTPromises', function () {

    it('should use a Promises/A+ compliant Promise library', function (done) {
        this.timeout(0);
        var adapter = {
            deferred: function() {
                var d = {}
                var executor = function(resolve, reject) {
                    d.resolve = resolve
                    d.reject  = reject
                };
                d.promise = new HTTPromiseCompliance(executor);
                return d
            }
        }

        promisesAplusTests(adapter, function (err) {
            if (err != null) {
                console.log('promises Aplus Tests failed with ' + err.failures + ' failures');
            } else {
                console.log('promises Aplus Tests passed');                
            }
            done(err);
        });
    });
});
```

A grunt task for this is fired during the build process.

If anyone has any thoughts on 'my new thinking' I would be appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: `request-promise` don't "have" the then-badge - they're not a promise library. They just use it to show that they return compliant promises.